# Save Multiple Rows in DataBase Yii

Tags: yii, multirow

I'm having some difficulties with Yii.
In my project I have a two fields (and Id_status Artist) it is possible to insert multiple rows like the following example http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/extension?view=dynamicrows 
But the problem is that I am not able to save data in the database.
For this case I am working with three tables (tbl_song, tbl_artists, tbl_song_artists).

If anyone can help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this should work. Just use [Yii's Tabular Input](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table).

The trick is making sure your JavaScript that is dynamically adding new rows to your Form gives the new text inputs the right `name` and `id`, with a unique number.

You could probably just use a random number for the $i value, just so long as you use the `[]` syntax Yii will parse the $_POST input as an array which you can loop through in your action on the server, and save each row to the database.

I hope this hint helps - good luck!

Comment: Hello,
Before I would like to thank you for the answer.
I had followed this documentation Tabular Input but without success.
If you send my project to your email can see if you can solve my problem? I have been to several days trying to resolve this but so far without success.

thank you

Comment: I just found this, actually, which may help future folks solving this problem: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/141/javascript-tabular-input/